# Wordpress removing <p> tags?

Tags: posts, shortcode, tags

I'd already come across a case where Wordpress added `<p>` tags. However now I'm dealing with the opposite situation. When I add [] shortcodes inside `<p>` tags WordPress automatically removes `<p>` tags.

```
<p>[anyshortcode]Hello World[/anyshortcode]</p>
```

Becomes:

```
Hello World
```

Adding  dir="ltr" to `<p>` tags seems to fix the issue, maybe there is a way to add it programatically to all `<p>` tags?

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: You can use a Advaced tinymce plugin that is more powerfull and make also p tags worked.

Comment: use 'wpautop'. Ex: '<?php echo wpautop('[anyshortcode]'); ?>'

Answer (score 7):

This is pretty much what Foxsk8 mentioned in a comment, so credit should go to him, but these additional instructions will be useful. The WordPress plugin called [TinyMCE Advanced](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tinymce-advanced/) will solve your problem.

This plugin comes with an option inside `Settings > TinyMCE Advanced` that will fix your disappearing `<p>` tags. Mark the checkbox labeled `Stop removing the <p> and <br /> tags when saving and show them in the Text editor` and your `<p>` tags will be preserved.

Answer (score 1):

TinyMCE is programmed to make editing easy (which for us HTML savvy is often not the case).  By default is should not accept `<p>` tagging around [BLOCKS].  That is because "[]" are used for shortcode not only in WP but a ton of PHP based CMSs.  The shortcodes should have the appropriate content wrapper.

Meaning the solution is to add the `<p>` tags in your shortcode code so that your content is wrapped the way you want.

Answer (score 1):

As an additional to **Foxsk8** and **E. Serrano**. If post contains `<p>` around shortcodes, WP will still remove it. It does it in [shortcode_unautop](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/shortcode_unautop/) filter that is added in '\wp-includes\default-filters.php'. It ensures that shortcodes are not wrapped in `<p>...</p>`.

So, we need to remove them:

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'shortcode_unautop' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this below code in your function.php file

```
function content_formatter($content){

    $new_content = '';
    $pattern_full = '{(\[raw\].*?\[/raw\])}is';
    $pattern_contents = '{\[raw\](.*?)\[/raw\]}is';
    $pieces = preg_split($pattern_full, $content, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

    foreach ($pieces as $piece) {
            if (preg_match($pattern_contents, $piece, $matches)) {
                    $new_content .= $matches[1];
            } else {
                    $new_content .= wptexturize(wpautop($piece));
            }
    }

    $array = array(
            '<p>[' => '[',
            ']</p>' => ']',
            ']<br />' => ']'
    );

    $new_content = strtr($new_content, $array);

    return $new_content;
```

}

Now call this function whereever required like;

```
<?php echo content_formatter( get_field('field_name') ); ?>
```

Comment: A little bit of would be good instead of just posting code.

Answer (score -2):

Append this to your functions.php file within your theme's folder.

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
```

Comment: See this also in other places. Does not work for me.